# Can I give very specific rights to an API user in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

For a developer using API in Marketing Cloud, can we give specific rights ( more than a simple Read/Write/Send) ?
Like being able to delete only the content created by this access ?
Or being able to send only transactional emails but no commercial emails ?
Or being able to send Emails only to Tests Data Extensions in a first time (then later we would open more rights so he would be able to send to all DE) ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the only permissions you can manage are the ones you can see in the Server-to-Server Properties of the package:

[image]

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your answer !